# In R, how to convert a string like "Saturday, 5 Oct 2013 20:31:59" to "2013-10-05 Saturday 20:31:59"?

Tags: r, date

How to convert a string which is `Saturday, 5 Oct 2013 20:31:59` to a datetime format `2013-10-05 Saturday 20:31:59`? Thanks. Or how to get the `year`, `month`, `date`, `day of the week`, `hour`, `minute`, `second` values from the string?

Comment: This is a good read: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/dates.html (at least I liked it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the relevant format specification when you create the time object from the string, eg:

```
(x <- as.POSIXct("Saturday, 5 Oct 2013 20:31:59", format="%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
[1] "2013-10-05 20:31:59 BST"
```

Look at `?strftime` to see the format specifications, and how to extract specific parts of a datetime.

```
#your desired format
format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %A %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-10-05 Saturday 20:31:59"
#only the year
format(x,"%Y")
[1] "2013"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> now <- Sys.time()
> now
[1] "2014-01-16 16:58:23 IST"
> as.POSIXlt(as.character(now),tz="GMT")
[1] "2014-01-16 17:05:24 GMT"
> str(as.POSIXlt(now))
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2014-01-16 16:58:23"
> unclass(as.POSIXlt(now))
$sec
[1] 23.1636

$min
[1] 58

$hour
[1] 16

$mday
[1] 16

$mon
[1] 0

$year
[1] 114

$wday
[1] 4

$yday
[1] 15

$isdst
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "Saturday, 5 Oct 2013 20:31:59"
dmy_hms(x)
## [1] "2013-10-05 20:31:59 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

R> date <- now()

R> year(date)
```

use the below accessor for other

```
Date component Accessor
Year           year()
Month          month()
Week           week()
Day of year    yday()
Day of month   mday()
Day of week    wday()
Hour           hour()
Minute         minute()
Second         second()
Time           zone tz()
```